# Using camera in opencv

Tags: opencv

I want to make a robot and I should do live image processing.so I need to take video from somewhere from a camera (canon powershot A3100) and process it.note that taking video is live means that when the camera got the frame I should process that frame.
I'm using CaptureFromCam(0) that uses integral webcam . I also used 1 instead of 0 but it doesn't find the camera!
Please help me